# How to insert user_id to coffeescript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm stacked. Have model User and Event and also fullcalendar.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
    events: '/events.json'
  )
```

Here is my coffeescript file but it doesnt work because it needs to be `events: '<%=@user.id%>/events.json'`. But ruby-code can't be in coffeescript file, so I need to get `user_id`.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible when the html is being generated. One way is to put in the bottom of your file js code which assigns user's id to globally available configuration and then read this id from this variable.

for example in your erb

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.Configuration = {};
  window.Configuration.UserId = <%= @user.id %>
<% end %>
```

And later in your coffee file 
`events: "#{window.Configuration.UserId}/events.json"`